# VBA: Create New Workbook on a specific Directory

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a new workbook on a specific directory using a button from an activeworkbook.

Directory will be Drive D:\SALES_RFQ Database

WorkBook name is "M.O Control Number Database"

Condition:
The code has to check if the workbook does exists, if not, if has to create the workbook on the given directory.

Any help with much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you found online guides how to do this?

Comment: What have you researched, and if so, what part of code are you confused about/do you need help with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Path As String, DocName As String

    Path = "D:\SALES_RFQ Database"
    DocName = "M.O Control Number Database"

    If Dir(Path & "\" & DocName & ".xlsx") = "" Then
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "\" & DocName & ".xlsx"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot    @Error for the help, that worked pretty fine.