# Change path, to Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have found the below code on this page, and it works fine. But I would like it to save it to a folder, based on my value of my cell, in this case C1

Eg. root file is found at: `C:\Users\john`
I would like it to be saved at another place, based on my value in C1, `C:\Users\john\games\new`
To what ever path I put in C1, that is where the file should be saved.
Hope you understand, and looking forward to any help or advise.

```
Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range, rw As Range, c As Range
    Dim p As String, v As String

    Set Rng = Selection

    'process each selected row
    For Each rw In Rng.Rows
        p = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" 'set initial root path for this row
        'process each cell in this row
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            v = Trim(c.Value) 'what's in the cell?
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                If Len(Dir(p & v, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir (p & v) 'create if not already there
                p = p & v & "\" 'append to path (regardless of whether it needed to be created)
            End If
        Next c
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your issue? Where did you get stuck or errors? We need a description of what went wrong. See [mcve] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Hi, if you specify localization (cell"C1") and name(DocName) of a workbook to save then you can just create new workbook with `Workbook.Add` and then save it with `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "\" & DocName & ".xlsx"` . Knowledge from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666280/vba-create-new-workbook-on-a-specific-directory)